# How can one thread tell another thread to stop?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a Service that creats a thread in the Oncreate methed.  this thread is a endless loop thAT PLAYS A MP3 FILE, GOES TO SLEEP FOR 30 SECONDS.

i'M TRYING TO FIGURE OUT HOW TO stop this in the onDestroy methed

code

public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nysound);
    mThread=new myThread();
    mThread.start();
}

public class myThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        do{
            mediaPlayer.start();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000*20);
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                ted++;
            }

        } while(true);
    }  // end methed
} // end class

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: What's with thE ODD CAPITALIZATION?

Comment: Also, what's with `try..catch` around `Thread.sleep()`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `boolean` flag for that

```
public class myThread extends Thread {

  private volatile boolean running = true;
  public void run() {
    do{
        mediaPlayer.start();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000*20);
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            ted++;
        }

    } while(running);
  }  // end methed

  public void setRunning(boolean newValue) {
    this.running = newValue;
  }
} //
```

And then do the following in main thread

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  mThread.setRunning(false);
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking but I would have to wait for the sleep to end.  Looks like its the inly save way to do it.

Comment: @Tedpottel, you could also use `mThread.interrupt()` but in this case you need to handle `InterruptedException` in your loop differently, like this `catch(InterruptedException in) {running = false}`

Answer (score 0):

## Calling onDestroy() is not the right way to stop Service

public void onDestroy () is called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed. The service should clean up any resources it holds (threads, registered receivers, etc) at this point. Upon return, there will be no more calls in to this Service object and it is effectively dead. Do not call this method directly.

#### if you are in service class please call method

stopSelf();

#### if you are in another class, like your MusicPlayerActivity call below code

Intent i = new Intent(this, ServiceName.class);
stopService(i);

Both of these will stop your service.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using higer-level object ScheduledExecutorService to handle thread execution :

```
 public void onCreate() { Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nysound);
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = 
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduledFuture = ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyThread(), 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    public class myThread extends Thread {

        public void run() {
                mediaPlayer.start();
        }  // end methed
    } // end class

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        scheduledFuture.cancel(true);

    }
```